# weird change from char to int , serial port communication c

Tags: c, serial-port, stack

I am working an a serial communication project where two applications server and client will send to each other messages.

For example client send a string command server receives this and after processing response with a value. One example of that is : **`client AT+REG1 server value`**.

If client sends the message `AT+REG1=value` then the server must inform his system that the value of current `register1` which `client` needs has changed.

In order to achieve this I keep a stack where at the beginning of the program I am pushing into stack a default value for register1 and if server detect this message AT+REG1= pops the old value and push the new  into stack.

Currently if client sends the message AT+REG1, server must response with the new value  and not with the old one that I push it by default in the beginning. All the stuff in pop push and generally at stack operations are going right.

**My problem is**, when I start with `AT+REG1`, client receives the default value but when I start with `AT+REG1=5` (server must change the value from the stack and replace it with the new "5") I am not getting any response. At this point I have to mention that in terminal I am seeing the changes in the stack (with printf for example at AT+REG1=5 , he pops the old and push the new) but I cannot have the result.

The problem that I noticed when trying to print the value that pops out from stack terminal says that it is of type  int **DESPITE** that am not using or creating integers, all the values are in char form.

```
SERVER.C
//data structures
typedef enum operation{
    insert,
    read_reg,
    info
}Operation;
typedef struct request{
    Operation operation;
    char old_value1[SIZE];   
    char old_value2[SIZE];
    int flag;           //flag to know which register is 
    int counter1;
    int counter2;
}Request; 
Request c1;
Request c2;




//Prototype Functions
Request *parse_request(char *buffer);
void process_request(int fd);
int isEmpty(char *stack);
int isFull(char *stack);
void push(char num,char *stack);
char pop(char *stack);

char *stack1,*stack2;
int top1=-1,top2=-1;
char t1,t2;

int main(int argc , char * argv[]){

    int fd;                //file descriptor of the port 
    char *port;            // port name 
    struct termios tty;    //connection manager 
    

    stack1=(char*)malloc(STACK_SIZE*sizeof(char));
    stack2=(char*)malloc(STACK_SIZE*sizeof(char));
        
    if(argc < 1){
        printf("You have to enter a specific tty file to open\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Opening port .
    port =argv[1];
    fd=open(port,O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY| O_NONBLOCK);
    
    if(fd==-1){
        perror(port);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] port opened succesfully!\n");

    if(tcgetattr(fd,&tty)!=0){
        printf("tcgetattr : %s \n",strerror(errno));
    }
    //BAUD RATE SETTINGS (read and write speed)
    cfsetospeed(&tty,B115200); 
    cfsetispeed(&tty,B115200);
    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    // Settings for control modes 
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;            // Clear the parity bit for the serial communication
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;            // Using only one stop bit in this communication 
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;                // Set 8 bits per byte in transmittion
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;           // Disable the RTS/CTS flow control 
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;     // Setting clocal up ("1") .Usefull for reading data 
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;            // Setting on the non-canonical mode 
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;              // Disable the INTR - QUIT - SUSP  characters 
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNPAR;
    
    //Blocking read operation and setting maximum timeout 1 second 
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]=1;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] =0;
    

    //Setting the options 
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&tty);
    
    //setting first values for each register!
    push('0',stack1);
    push('1',stack2);
    
    c1.counter1=0;
    c2.counter2=0;
    printf("[+] Connection starting !\n");
    
    while(1){
        
        process_request(fd);
    
    }
 
}

Request *parse_request(char *buffer){

    char *token=NULL;
    char *take[3];
    int i=0,num;
    Request *rep=NULL;

    
    if(!buffer)
        return NULL;
        
    rep=(Request*)malloc(sizeof(Request));
    memset(rep->old_value1,0,SIZE);
    memset(rep->old_value2,0,SIZE);
    
    if(strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG1")==0) {
        rep->operation=read_reg;
        rep->flag=1;
    }else if(strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG2")==0){
        rep->operation=read_reg;
        rep->flag=2;
    }else if(strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG2")!=0 || strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG1")!=0){
    
        token=strtok(buffer,"=");
        while(token!=NULL){
            take[i]=token;
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }
        if(strcmp(take[0],"AT+REG1")==0 && strcmp(take[1],"?")==0){
            rep->operation=info;
            rep->flag=1;
        }else if(strcmp(take[0],"AT+REG2")==0 && strcmp(take[1],"?")==0){
            rep->operation=info;
            rep->flag=2;
        }else if(strcmp(take[0],"AT+REG1")==0 && take[1]!=NULL){
            rep->operation=insert;
            rep->flag=1;
            //Scanning for errors
            if(atoi(take[1])>16535 || atoi(take[1])<0)
                return rep=NULL;        
            char rev;
            if(!isEmpty(stack1)){
                
                //take the old value from the stack and save it 
                
                rep->old_value1[c1.counter1]=pop(stack1);
                c1.counter1++;
                int num=atoi(take[1]);
                rev= num;
                push(rev,stack1);
                
            }else{
                //push the new value into the stack
                int num=atoi(take[1]);
                rev= num;
                push(rev,stack1);
            }
        }else if(strcmp(take[0],"AT+REG2")==0 && take[1]!=NULL){
            rep->operation=insert;
            rep->flag=2;
            
            //Scanning for errors
            if(atoi(take[1])>3 || atoi(take[1])<1)
                return rep=NULL;        

            char rev;
            if(!isEmpty(stack2)){
                rep->old_value2[c2.counter2]=pop(stack2);
                c2.counter2++;
                int num=atoi(take[1]);
                rev=num;
                push(rev,stack2);
            }else{
                int num=atoi(take[1]);
                rev=num;
                push(rev,stack2);
            }   
        }else{
            free(rep);
            return(NULL);
        }
    }else{
        free(rep);
        return(NULL);
    }
    
    return rep;
}
void process_request(int fd){


    fd_set readfd;
    int status;
    char *str;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    int read_num=0;
    char *str1;
    struct flock fl;
    struct timeval timeout;
    Request *request;
    
    
    
    
    fl.l_type   = F_RDLCK;  /* read lock */
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET; /* beginning of file */
    fl.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
    fl.l_len    = 0;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
    fl.l_pid    = getpid(); /* PID */
    
    
    
    //Clean buffer
    memset(buffer,0,SIZE);
    
     FD_ZERO(&readfd);
     FD_SET(fd,&readfd);
    timeout.tv_sec=100;
     timeout.tv_usec=0;
            
    status=select(40,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
            
    if(status==0){ //no data is receiving !
                
        printf("Cannot receive data from client\n");
        printf("\tTime Out\n");
        exit(1);
 
    }
    
    //read from file descriptor
    read_num=read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if(read_num<0)perror("Error in reading\n");
    
    if(read_num){
        fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl); // set lock 
        str1=strdup(buffer);
        request = parse_request(str1);
        if(request){
            switch(request->operation){
                case info:
                    if(request->flag==1){
                        write(fd,"0-16535\n",20);
                    }else if(request->flag==2){
                        write(fd,"1|2|3\n",40);
                    }
                    break;
                case read_reg:
                    if(request->flag==1){
                        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
                        t1=pop(stack1);
                        printf("%s\n",t1); // it understand this as int why ?
                        write(fd,&t1,5);
                        //---------------
                    }else if(request->flag==2){
                        
                        t2=pop(stack2);
                        write(fd,&t2,sizeof(t2));
                    }
                    break;
                case insert:
                    if(request==NULL)
                        write(fd,"INVINPUT\n",20);
                    write(fd,"OK\n",5);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Something went wrong\n");
                    break;
            }
            if(request)
                free(request);
        }
    }
    fl.l_type   = F_UNLCK;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl); // unset lock 

}

int isEmpty(char *stack){
    if(stack==stack1){
        if(top1==-1)
            return 1;
        return 0;   
    }else if(stack==stack2){
        if(top2==-1)
            return 1;
        return 0;

    }
    
}
int isFull(char *stack){
    if(stack==stack1){
        if(top1==STACK_SIZE)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }else if(stack==stack2){
        if(top2==STACK_SIZE)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
void push(char num,char *stack){
    
    if(stack==stack1){
        if(!isFull(stack1)){
            printf("Eisagogh\n");
            top1++;
            //*(stack+top1)=num;
            stack1[top1]=num;
        }else{
            printf("Error , push at stack1\n");
        }
    
    }else if(stack==stack2){
        if(!isFull(stack2)){
            top2++;
            *(stack2+top2)=num;
        }else
            printf("Error , push at stack2\n");
        
    }
}


char pop(char *stack){
    
    char str_num;
    if(stack==stack1){
        if(!isEmpty(stack)){
            printf("Eksagogh\n");
            str_num=*(stack+top1);
            top1--;
            return str_num;
        }else
            printf("Error in pop item from stack1\n");
    }else if(stack==stack2){
        printf("me vlepeis edo ?\n");
        if(!isEmpty(stack)){
            str_num=*(stack+top2);
            top2--;
            return str_num;
        }else
            printf("Error in pop item from stack2\n");
    }
}
```

Running :

```
CLIENT
AT+REG1=5
writing AT+REG1=5 command
Response:OK
AT+REG1
writing AT+REG1 command
Responce : 

SERVER
[+] port opened succesfully!
push //it is the default value that I insert into the stack
[+] Connection starting !
pop // pops out the default value 
push // seems that inserting the value 5 that client asked
pop // and now that pop is for writing to serial port in order client reads it (HERE IS THE PROBLEM) this is the point where I mention in the code that I have problem terminal seeing it as integer and not as char , go check this at process_requst function in server above.
```

If client sends although AT+REG1 he response the default value where server pops out from stack and send it in the point where the problem is . Please if anyone can help i would appreciate.

Comment: Thats way too much code for Stack Overflow. You need to reduce that to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But why is a stack needed? If you are pushing and popping one value all the time then it would seem a simple variable would suffice.

Comment: You pass `buffer` to `strdup`, but you can only pass `strdup` a C-style string, which `buffer` isn't. Nowhere is there code to actually receive a message and assemble it into a C-style string despite the rest of your code assuming that's been done.

Comment: _Side note:_ To be safe, you may wish to add: `tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;`

Comment: In `parse_request`, your `if/else` ladder logic is too complex [and _broken_]. For example, the third line: `}else if(strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG2")!=0 || strcmp(buffer,"AT+REG1")!=0){` can just be `} else {` because of the prior two `if/else` make it _always_ true. The nested block of `if/else` under that is broken because the `strcmp` will always return `!= 0` because you _never_ get into the block if the string is `"AT+REG1"` or `"AT+REG2"`

Comment: 'read_num=read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));' can this not return with incomplete messages in non-canonical?   Sorry, but your protocol is unclear - how are your messages framed and how/where are they parsed from the input stream?